# Authorization in google with using OAuth 2 without browser

Tags: java, google-authentication

Please tell me if there is some sample code that allows you to log in to Google Spreadsheets using Java and Google OAuth 2 without recourse to the browser?
I found them a code sample, but it is only for .NET

Answer (score -1, accepted):

An overview of using OAuth2 with Java can be found here: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-oauth-java-client/oauth2

You can learn more about using OAuth2 and Java to perform authentication and authorisation for Google services here: 
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2#overview

Both guides instruct the reader on how to use the OAuth2 API and include Java code samples.

Comment: thank you! I already found the answer there. and here - https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client-samples/blob/master/oauth2-cmdline-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/oauth2/cmdline/OAuth2Sample.java